# Can i replace an existing normal table with a materialized view

Tags: oracle, synchronization, materialized-views

I've searched but found no answer, so i resort to you.

I have an Oracle table, say "Countries" that exists for ages in database 2 (target).
Now, we want to synchronize that table from a "Countries" table in database 1 (source).
However the existing Countries table (target), has pk, constraints, triggers, etc and is referenced by several other tables.

Question:
Could i replace the target table with a Materialized view (MV) ?
If so, i would have to recreate all those pk, constraints, triggers, on this MV, and also alter all those tables that reference the original table, right ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a materialized view using an *existing* table with the `ON PREBUILT TABLE` clause. It will create the automation, etc. for the MV and update the original table. See documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-MATERIALIZED-VIEW.html#GUID-EE262CA4-01E5-4618-B659-6165D993CA1B

> ON PREBUILT TABLE Clause
>
> The ON PREBUILT TABLE clause lets you register an existing table as a
> preinitialized materialized view. This clause is particularly useful
> for registering large materialized views in a data warehousing
> environment. The table must have the same name and be in the same
> schema as the resulting materialized view.
>
> If the materialized view is dropped, then the preexisting table
> reverts to its identity as a table.
>
> Note:This clause assumes that the table object reflects the
> materialization of a subquery. Oracle strongly recommends that you
> ensure that this assumption is true in order to ensure that the
> materialized view correctly reflects the data in its master tables.
> The ON PREBUILT TABLE clause could be useful in the following
> scenarios:
>
> You have a table representing the result of a query. Creating the
> table was an expensive operation that possibly took a long time. You
> want to create a materialized view on the query. You can use the ON
> PREBUILT TABLE clause to avoid the expense of executing the query and
> populating the container for the materialized view.
>
> You temporarily discontinue having a materialized view, but keep its
> container table, using the DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW ... PRESERVE TABLE
> statement. You then decide to recreate the materialized view and you
> know that the master tables of the view have not changed. You can
> create the materialized view using the ON PREBUILT TABLE clause. This
> avoids the expense and time of creating and populating the container
> table for the materialized view.
>
> If you specify ON PREBUILT TABLE, then Oracle database does not create
> the I_SNAP$ index. This index improves fast refresh performance. If
> you want the benefits of this index, then you can create it manually.
> Refer to Oracle Database Data Warehousing Guide for more information.